# How to disable Log4j for OpenNLP via log4j.properties

Tags: java, logging, log4j, opennlp

I use Log4j and I import OpenNLP via Maven. Now I want to disable the log output (in red) which is printed in syso from opennlp.

I tried to add to my log4j.properties:

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout

# Direct log messages to stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out

log4j.appender.org.opennlp=OFF
```

The last line should hide opennlp messages such as:

Average: 1000,0 sent/s 
Total: 1 sent
Runtime: 0.001s

but does not work. Please tell me why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenNLP is not using Log4j, or any other logging framework. The command line interface prints directly to stdout. The command line tools are only useful for training/evaluating and testing.

For production use you should integrate OpenNLP via its Java API, or via some other framework like Apache UIMA.